# Array Struct and array

Tags: c

I wrote some code:). I don't know make it work. It work when I use array but it doesn't work when I use array of structs. In my program I use library function to take data from inside database and it look like that:

```
int opfGetAll( void *opf,const char *info, const char *name, void *parms )
```

`opf` - pointer to db
`info` - the info type
`name` - name of parameter
`parm` - the array output, this must be of the correct type

```
int main()
{
    struct data
    {
        int intVal;
        float floatVal;
        double doubleVal;
     };

     //struct data *iform1_tab = malloc(sizeof(struct data)*number_locs);
     float *iform1_tab = malloc(sizeof(float)*number_locs);
     if(iform1 ==2 )//FLOAT
     {
         //opfGetAll(opf,type1,attr_inp1, &iform1_tab[0].floatVal);//don't take all data, it fill half of it and the rest is 0 or rubbish
         opfGetAll(opf,type1,attr_inp1, iform1_tab );//this version fill all array

     }


 }
```

Comment: The array of `struct data` is overwriten (you loose the array and introduce a memory leak) in the second call to `malloc`

Comment: where does `iform1` in `if(iform1 ==2 )` come from?

Comment: I don't use this malloc at this same time. I use them interchangeably. This same with opfGetAll:).

Comment: iform1 isn't a merritum.This shows that the data being read is of a float type.

Comment: Well, first I think we need to know what do you expect from your code !

Comment: I want to read data from outside database and put it to array. When I read it to array it work. It doesn't work when i use array of struct. It only read half of data. The rest of array struct ( iform_tab[].floatVal ) is rabbish.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add all relevant information there instead of answering in comments. How does your function `opfGetAll` know if `void *parms` points to an array of `struct` or an array of `float` and how big your array is? If you pass `&iform1_tab[0].floatVal`, it cannot know how to find `iform1_tab[1].floatVal` etc.

Answer (score 1):

More needs to be known (and posted) about the internals of the function `opfGetAll()` for a more complete answer.  The 4th argument, `void *`, means the function is likely set up to handle more than one type of input.  Whether that includes `flaot *` is not known, but from what you are trying, and without more accurate documentation, the assumption appears you expect that is can.

However, from your comments following the two ways you have called the functions:

```
 //opfGetAll(opf,type1,attr_inp1, &iform1_tab[0].floatVal);//don't take all data, it fill half of it and the rest is 0 or rubbish
 opfGetAll(opf,type1,attr_inp1, iform1_tab );//this version fill all array
```

strongly suggests that the 4th argument of `opfGetAll` expects some form of `struct data *`, whether it be a single instance or an array.  If that is the case, this would be why you are seeing unexpected results when attempting to pass it something else.  (i.e. `&iform1_tab[0].floatVal`, which is a `float *`)

Comment: I did not specify the query. I don't use this declaration at the same time.I use them interchangeably. So this is not the problem.

Comment: @Kris_Holder - it appears the content of your post has changed from what I  posted this against, which changes things.  Regardless of those changes, the first malloc call you indicate, is compatible with the form of arguments in the statement you marked as `//don't take`.  Beyond that, edit your question to include _specifically what you want_.

Comment: So the struct version should work. But it doesn't and I don't know why:(.

Comment: @Kris_Holder - I just created an instance of your struct, and used its members in a test function with the prototype that includes a `float *var` as one of its arguments. It worked fine.   What is the exact prototype of the function `opfGetAll(?)`  (either reply here, or edit your OP with that information.  It is very relevant.)  If the 4th argument is _not_ prototyped as `float *`, then the argument as passed  in your first instance (commented now) will not work.

Comment: I put the prototype of the function at the top. I don't have more information:(. I Can write that it return 1 when something goes wrong.

Comment: @Kris_Holder - Do you not know how the function processes the 4th argument?  It has to know 1) what the type is. (I assume that is provided in 2nd argument )  And 2), it has to know how many instances of the `struct` have been passed. This is not apparent from the information in your post. In order to provide more accurate answer, more has to be known about internals of function `opfGetAll`.  I strongly suspect now, after taking a second look, argument 4 expects, and will populate memory corresponding to an array of struct.

Comment: @Kris_Holder - based on this conversation, and a second look at your question, including the apparent success you had on the 2nd call to `opfGetAll`, I have re-written my answer to address what I can with the limited information available for exactly what `opfGetAll` does.  I hope it helps.